# Deleting Records and getting (SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input)

Tags: ember-data

I am getting this above when deleting a record.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Here is the request:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8085
Request URL:http://localhost:8085/myproject/rest/bookingVehicles/100
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:200 OK
```

Here is the java method I am using:

I have tried this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void delete(@Min(1) @PathVariable("id") final long id) {
    bookingVehicleDao.delete(id);
}
```

And this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public String delete(@Min(1) @PathVariable("id") final long id) {
    bookingVehicleDao.delete(id);
    return "";
}
```

And this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public String delete(@Min(1) @PathVariable("id") final long id) {
    bookingVehicleDao.delete(id);
    return "";
}
```

Each time I am getting this error.  Doing a `.then()` on the result never runs because according to ember-data an error has occurred.  I am thinking maybe is has something to do with the HttpStatus.  What is the correct HTTP code for a DELETE?

On the server side the records is correctly deleted so it is definately something to do with the response that it is not liking.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, you need to return `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)`

So:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void delete(@Min(1) @PathVariable("id") final long id) {
    bookingVehicleDao.delete(id);
}
```